# Reverse algorithm to reverse polish notation

Tags: rpn

I know how RPN works, i.e. we have input:

```
a + b * c
```

and output is

```
bc*a+
```

Is it easy to create algorithm which shows me what is the last computation of this equation? I mean that I want to know that first operation is + on two sentences: "a" and "b*c".

Numerical equations are not connected with my problem but with logical sentences. For example I have a logical sentence:

```
p&(q|r)
```

and I need to divide this firstly to

```
p,(q|r) with &operator
```

and second sentence:

```
q,r with |operator
```

I need to create some kind of parser or something? Is it possible to achieve it relatively easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is somewhat unclear, but I try to answer the 'is it easy to create an algorithm which shows me what is the last computation'.

Think of rpn as a stack based method of calculation: so `bc*a+` means push (the value of) `b` on the stack, push `c` on the stack, apply `*` to the two topmost elements and push the result on the top of the stack. Then push `a` on the stack and apply `+` to the two topmost elements and push the result on the stack. So the last computation an rpn formula does is the right-most operator.

Logical sentences are exacty the same thing, just replace * with & and + with |.

Comment: I know who RPN works, but it doesn't help me, because I want to do algorithm which tells me all steps from the back.  RPN with logic operators gives me firstly (q,r with |operator) and then p,(q|r) with &operator, I want it from reverse. How to parse it in that way?